# Javascript Return value from function not accessible

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that is returning a value. However, I can not get the value to return outside of the function. I have researched and can not figure out the issue. It says grossResults in the last line of code is undefined. Wouldn't the return make it accessible?

```
"use script";

var hourlyRate = prompt("Enter hourly pay rate:", hourlyRate);
var totalHrsWorked = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", totalHrsWorked));


//function to calculate gross wages for an hourly employee
function grossWages (hourlyRate, totalHrsWorked){

var OTHours = totalHrsWorked - 40;
var regPay = (totalHrsWorked - OTHours) * hourlyRate;
var OTPay = (OTHours * (hourlyRate * 1.5)) + regPay;
grossResults = (OTHours > 0) ? OTPay : regPay;
return grossResults;
};


document.writeln("<br /><br />");
document.writeln("Pay rate entered: " + hourlyRate + "<br />");
document.writeln("Hours entered: " + totalHrsWorked  + "<br />");

document.writeln("Gross Pay: $" + grossResults + "<br /><br />")
```

Comment: Where are you calling `grossWages`? You merely defined the function, you didn't call it. The code inside the function got never executed. I recommend to read a [**JavaScript tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) before you proceed further, especially [about functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: I believe the last line was meant to be: `document.writeln("Gross Pay: $" + grossWages(hourlyRate, totalHrsWorked ) + "<br /><br />")   `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems.

First is understanding scope in javascript. JS has function scope, which basically means variables (and functions) declared inside a function are only visible inside that function (incl. its children). For more detail, see for ex. [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript). I'm skipping all about inheritance here, which works by prototypes, but it basically just defines hierarchical relationships between objects (so they can see variables/functions their parents have).

What scope means in your example's context is that `grossResults` is defined inside function `grossWages` so it's not visible outside that function. When function `grossWages` gets called (which never happens in your example, but what you're trying to achieve is probably `var grossResults = grossWages()` - in which case `grossWages()` returns the **value** of its variable `grossResults`, it doesn't expose that variable to the context outside that function.

Notes:
"use script" probably should be "use strict". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you aren't invoking the function. Javascript has support for first-class functions, which means you can use functions like strings/numbers and pass around their reference, which is why this doesn't error out when its run.

```
document.writeln("Gross Pay: $" + grossResults(hourlyRate, totalHrsWorked) + "<br /><br />")
```

The above code properly calls your functions, with your arguments you pulled in from the prompt!